# Run an .xlsm marco in Ubuntu

Tags: python, excel

I created a macro to convert .xlsm to .pdf. Now, I want put the .xlsm on a Ubuntu box, then use a Python script to call the convert macro automatically.

After dig in xlrd & xlwt libraries I found those do not support macros and the only way to call the macro is to use win32com.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're trying to run a MS Excel macro on a Linux system and have found that the linux libraries do not support macro execution.  You've found you can do this with win32com but wish to know if there's another way?

Comment: Thanks GHC, win32com only support windows platform. So i'd choice other way.

Comment: aren't macros visual basic? so you'd need a way to run visual basic on ubuntu..